# How to find a way of output the number of attempts for each question of the quiz?

Tags: c#, console

I am making the quiz application on C# in Console version.
 I have almost done all things, but I don't know how to show the number of attempts for each question, after when the quiz is finished. If you know something, let me know. 
I can not add more lines of the code, as the website doesn't allow to do it

```
                    if (keys[index] == answer) // Answer is correct
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations. That's correct!");
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        totalScore += markPerQuestion;
                        index++;

                        Console.WriteLine("The total score is: {0}", totalScore);
                        Console.WriteLine("Used attempt(s): {0}", attempt);

                        attempt = 1;
                        count = attempt;
                        markPerQuestion = 20;

                       
                    }
                    else // Answer is incorrect
                    {
                        attempt++;
                        count++;

                        if (attempt <= 3)
                        {
                            markPerQuestion /= 2; 

                        }

                        else if (attempt > 3 && attempt < 5) // The fourth attempt gives zero points
                        {
                            markPerQuestion = 0;
                            totalScore += markPerQuestion;
                        }

                        else if(attempt >= 5)  // Move to the next question
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you used all attempts for that question. Moving to the next question");
                            index++;
                            markPerQuestion = 20;
                            attempt = 1;
                            count = attempt;
                            continue;

                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Oops, try again");
                    }
                    if ((index > keys.Length - 1 && index > questions.Length - 1)) // Questions and answer keys are finished
                    {
                            for (int i = 0; i < questions.Length; i++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Question {0} was answered after {1} attempt(s)", (i + 1), count);
                            }
                        
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: If you show us your code (preferably as a [mcve]), we could make suggestions. Those suggestions would likely involve having a counter. Without that, there's not much to say. I'm answer to you question _("if you know something, let me know.")_, we do know something

Comment: Just a wild guess (do the lack of information), but you could create a `Dictionary<int,int>` with the `key` being a reference to the question and `value` being the number of guess. Then at the end do a foreach over the `Dictionary` printing `Console.WriteLine($"Question {key} :: # Guesses {value}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution:
Create a public class that will allow you to store the results.

```
public class QuizMark
{
    public int Attempts;
    public int Mark;
}
```

For the Console app create a method to control the Quiz. Call the method `Quiz()` from the `Main` method.

```
private const int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
private static void Quiz()
{
    var quizResults = new List<QuizMark>();
    var questionAnswers = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6 };
    foreach(var a in questionAnswers)
    {
        var v = QuizQuestion(a);
        quizResults.Add(v);
    }

    int i = 0;
    quizResults.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($"Question: {++i}  Attempts: {e.Attempts}  Mark: {e.Mark}"));

    var total = quizResults.Sum(s => s.Mark);
    Console.WriteLine($"Total Points: {total}");
}
```

Notice the `List` collection that stores an object of the class `QuizMark`. This is where the results of each question are stored: attempts and points.
The `List` questionAnswers simply contains the expected answer to each of the questions.

Now create the method that is going to control how each question in the quiz will be handled:

```
    private static QuizMark QuizQuestion(int answer)
    {
        var quizMark = new QuizMark();

        int guess = 0; //Store ReadLine in this variable
        int mark = 20;

        for (int attempt = 1; attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS + 1; attempt++)
        {
            guess++; //remove when adding Console.ReadLine
            if (guess.Equals(answer))
            {
                quizMark.Attempts = attempt;
                quizMark.Mark = mark;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                mark = attempt <= 3 ? mark/2 : 0;
                quizMark.Attempts = attempt;
                quizMark.Mark = mark;
            }
        }

        return quizMark;
    }
```

You will need to replace the incrementor `guess++` with the actual guess the user makes. This code is designed to go though automatically just as a demonstration.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

You will want to do some error handling any time you allow users to enter data. They might enter non-integer values. Probably using a loop around a `Console.ReadLine` where you check the value of the input with a `Int32.TryParse()`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but I have already found a solution